# How do I tell Rewrite that the link is GET and not a directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^explore/([0-9a-zA-Z\ ]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) renderpage.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&subsubmenu=$3 [NC]
```

and when I type www.mysite.com/explore/Servizi%20ADR/Mediazione/Regolamento (excuse the italian)

1. It takes forever to load
2. When it finally loads and I 'inspect element' the source links for css and js are like if they were in `"explore/Servizi%20ADR/Mediazione/Regolamento/jquery.js "`

So my guess is I have to write something like a RewriteCond, but I don't know what exactly

Comment: When using mod_rewrite like this, you need to refer to any external resources (images/js/css/etc) using absolute paths or else the browser will see the url and make requests under those folders. This is not something you should fix with htaccess or even try. external resources should be referred to in the source like `/js/jquery.js` or `/imgs/image.png`. The issue is that the browser doesn't know that `/explore/whatever/` is not a folder and there is no good way to tell it that. If you don't want this effect, then you shouldn't be rewriting urls in the first place.

Comment: ok, I see, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use conditions to not include real files or dirs. And also use a base path for files like this

```
RewriteEngine On
#if requested URI is real file or dir, do nothing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#else process the rule
RewriteRule ^explore/([0-9a-zA-Z\ ]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/? renderpage.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&subsubmenu=$3 [NC,L]
```

Also you can put the base tag in the **head** section of your html, instead of using absolute paths for your js and css.

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com" />
```